# prevent gridview row duplication asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a web page that contain dropdownlist, session[student-id], button, gridview

student will choose the course from the dropdownlist and click on the register button then the student-id and the selected course will be added to the gridview.

My question is how can I show error message for the student if he has already register this course.

I mean I want the register button to check in the database if this student has the selected course.

Any help??

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

simply use the query on btn_click event

```
int stu_id=int.Parse(stu_id.Text);
query="select stu_id from table where username='"+stu_id+"'";
if(query)
//already registered student
else
//new student
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you're looking for, but without seeing any of your initial code it will be pretty much impossible to realize what you're looking for exactly. Therefore I'm going to present two of these possible methods to you.

1. First and most obvious way of dealing with duplicates in your case
   would be removing the selected course from the DropDownList upon
   registration. That way, there is no way a user would be able to
   select the same course more than once.
        Code sample:

   ```
           public void RemoveCourseByCourseID(string courseID)
           {
               if(courseList == null || courseList.Items.Count == 0)
                   return;

               ListItem courseItem = courseList.Items.FindByValue(courseID);

               if(courseItem == null)
                   return;

               courseList.Remove(courseItem);
           }
   ```
2. Second method is to run a check on each one of the GridView rows and
   validate the nonexistence of the selected course.  Here's a
       sample code which you can use to your own benefit:

   ```
       public bool IsCourseExist(string courseID)
       {
           const int columnCourseID = 0;
           foreach(DataRow row in gridView.Rows)
           {
               if(row[columnCourseID].ToString() == courseID)
                   return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   ```

Comment: I tried this code but it is not working >>>>>>>>>>>

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];


                if (row.Cells[0].Text == DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString())
                {
                    //display error message
                }

                else
                {
                  // I have the code for adding the data to gridview and it works fine

                }

Comment: there is no error but the course is registered even if the if statement is ture

Comment: Are you sure the column index you're validating your Course ID against is the right one (index 0)?

Comment: When I removed the for loop and write this GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[1] I mean specify which row I want it works fine, but when I want to search in all rows it not work

Comment: Seems to me there's a problem in your code adjustment. There is absolutely no reason for your code not to work using the foreach loop.

Comment: Post your working and not working codes in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

/Using linq**/
        var result = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 group c by new
                                 {

```
                                 RiskDescription2 = c.Field<dynamic>("Risk description "),


                             } into g
                             where g.Count() > 1
                             select new
                             {
                                 g.Key.RiskDescription2,

                                 //  g.Key.Pin,
                                 Noofrec = g.Count()
                             };

                if (result.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    lblErrMsg.Visible = true;
                    div_err_log.Visible = false;
                    lblErrMsg.Text = "Risk with same description not allowed.";
                    return;
                }
```